# Contatenated double matrices are now of type complex double: why?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a set of double matrices stored in text files. I create another file by just vertically concatenating a set of these double matrices text files. The problem is the fact that the concatenated file if read in matlab is now of type complex double. I want this matrix to be of type double as the mother files are.

The concatenation is done by a very stupid code. In a loop i just do the vertical concatenation after reading the files

```
   //outside the loop
   vector=dlmread(['fv/test_feature_vectors/' new_name '.txt']);
   //loop begin 
   vector2=dlmread(['fv/test_feature_vectors/' new_name2 ]);
   vector=vertcat(vector,vector2); 
   //loop end
   dlmwrite(['fv/train_feature_vectors/fold' int2str(i-2) '.txt'], vector);
```

If I do a whos command over the vector variable, I have:

```
   whos vector                  
   Name           Size                 Bytes      Class    Attributes
   vector         10577x705            119308560  double    complex
```

If I do the same in last vector2 variable, I have:

```
   Name          Size              Bytes      Class     Attributes
   vector2       22x705            124080     double
```

Why this happens? why the verticaly concatenated matrices are of type complex double? are some of my text files with complex double values and i didn' t noticed (i have hundreds of files)? how to get rid of this?

Comment: If I do final_vector=real(vector) the variable final_vector is now of type double. Is this a good solution? will I lose lots of information?

Comment: How did you produce or acquire the text files that you're reading in? Maybe somewhere there was a use of `i` or `j` before initializing them as variables? In that case, they call the functions `i()` or `j()` which return the imaginary unit, and could "contaminate" your values.

Comment: @AndrewJanke that's a good point. I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data that has been written to files `'fv/test_feature_vectors/' new_name/2 '.txt'` was complex then in the text file it will be written as real + i imaginary. Then it will also be read as complex double.

If you know that it was real you can safely ignore the imaginary part with `real`.

The problem then is earlier. The data written to the files should not have been complex, so likely there is a minor bug somewhere before.